# Item sorting does not work, magento 2

Tags: magento2

Position sorting does not work.

Whatever I specified values ​​in position on the front is always displayed in the same sequence.

> admin

[image]

> front

[image]

Comment: Try with 0,1,2 then do reindex and guess it work out

Comment: I tried, it did not help

Comment: Give it 0 to all then save and refresh front then do sorting o,1,2 etc.., trick

Comment: Did but it also did not help

Comment: Which Magento 2 version are you using ?